# Android embedded h2database no permissions

Tags: java, android, database, h2

After trying to get h2database to work for about 8 hours, I decided to post here to get some help.

```
        try {

        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", "test", "test");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE table1 ( user varchar(50) )");
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table1 ( user ) VALUES ( 'Claudio' )");
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table1 ( user ) VALUES ( 'Bernasconi' )");
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table1 ( user ) VALUES ( 'Mauro' )");
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO table1 ( user ) VALUES ( 'Jeffrey' )");
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table1");
        while (rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString("user");
            tokens.add(name);
        }
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (JdbcSQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getSQL());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getClass());
        System.out.println("exception");

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

The following error occured: "open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)" while executing DriverManager.getConnection()

Seems to me Android doesn't have the correct permissions to write files to internal storage.

Anyone who had this issue before and knows a solution? Getting desperate.

Thanks in advance,

Greetings Mauro